# *= in Sybase SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, join, sybase

I'm maintaining some code that uses a *= operator in a query to a Sybase database and I can't find documentation on it.  Does anyone know what *= does?  I assume that it is some sort of a join.

```
select * from a, b where a.id *= b.id
```

I can't figure out how this is different from:

```
select * from a, b where a.id = b.id
```

Comment: Please keep care. It's deprecated nowadays and needs explicit activation on database configuration.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.dc34982_1500/html/mig_gde/mig_gde160.htm:

Inner and outer tables

The terms outer table and inner table describe the placement of the tables in an outer join:

- In a left join, the outer table and inner table are the left and right tables respectively. The outer table and inner table are also referred to as the row-preserving and null-supplying tables, respectively.
- In a right join, the outer table and inner table are the right and left tables respectively.

For example, in the queries below, T1 is the outer table and T2 is the inner table:

- T1 left join T2
- T2 right join T1

Or, using Transact-SQL syntax:

- T1 *= T2
- T2 =* T1

Comment: wow, thanks sybase for making this sound comlicated and confusing.

Comment: It appears link you provided says about different things.

Answer (score 9):

It means outer join, a simple = means inner join.

```
*= is LEFT JOIN and =* is RIGHT JOIN.
```

(or vice versa, I keep forgetting since I'm not using it any more, and Google isn't helpful when searching for *=)

Answer (score 6):

Of course, you *should* write it this way:

```
SELECT *
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b ON b.id=a.id
```

The a,b syntax is evil.

Comment: I dunno about evil, but it is certainly proprietary to Sybase and Microsoft SQL Server, and not supported by other brands of database.

Answer (score 5):

ANSI-82 syntax

```
select 
    * 
from 
    a
  , b 

where 
     a.id *= b.id
```

ANSI-92

```
select 
    * 
from 
   a
  left outer join b 
      on a.id = b.id
```

Comment: I think you mean SQL-89 and SQL-92, not ANSI-82 and ANSI-92.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from a, b where a.id = b.id
```

Requires that a row exist in where b.id = a.id in order to return an answer

```
select * from a, b where a.id *= b.id
```

Will fill the columns from b with nulls when there wasn't a row in b where b.id = a.id.